# Window manager blocking keyboard for apps underneath floating chat head

Tags: android, service, keyboard-events, android-windowmanager

I have an app in which i have implemented chat heads just like facebook messenger app It works fine but once keyboard is used by my floating chat head other apps cant open keyboard. I am using window manager to show floating view this is how i am setting my layout params in window manager

````
public static WindowManager.LayoutParams getWindowManagerOutsideRoom(){
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL ,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        } else {
            params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL ,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        }
        params.screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        return params;
    } ```

any help in this regard will me much appreciated
````

Answer (score 0):

So I figure out it my self by reading Window manager flags, The solution was to use different Flags when you want touches to be handled and when not, Posting the snippet ``

```
public static WindowManager.LayoutParams enableKeyPadInput(Boolean enable) {
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            if (enable) {
                params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

            } else {
                params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            }
        } else {
            if (enable) {
                params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

            } else {
                params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            }
        }

        params.screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        return params;
    }
```

``